# How to add autoplay to image slider using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and I'm having a hard time trying to implement autoplay to my image slider.

I guess I would have to use `setTimeout()` but I can't tell where.
I was taking a look at the w3schools tutorial and I've tried to add the animation by creating an `autoPlay()` function, using a `for loop`, `setTimeout()`, and calling the function inside `init()`, but that didn't work. Could someone help me? I appreciate it

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a7d8945663.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Image Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="slide-btn-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>

      <div class="container-slider">
        <div class="slide-img">
          <img src="./img/odin.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
          <img src="./img/web-1.jpeg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
          <img src="./img/web-2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide-btn-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation-dots"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
const slideImage = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-img');
const slideContainer = document.querySelector('.container-slider');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.slide-btn-next');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.slide-btn-prev');
const navigationDots = document.querySelector('.navigation-dots');

let numberOfImages = slideImage.length;
let slideWidth = slideImage[0].clientWidth;
let currentSlide = 0;

//set up slider

function init() {
  slideImage.forEach((img, i) => {
    img.style.left = i * 100 + '%';
  });
  slideImage[0].classList.add('active');

  createNavigationDots();
}

//create navigatiton dots
function createNavigationDots() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
    const dot = document.createElement('div');
    dot.classList.add('single-dot');
    navigationDots.appendChild(dot);

    dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
      goToSlide(i);
    });
  }

  navigationDots.children[0].classList.add('active');
}

//next & prev buttons
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentSlide >= numberOfImages - 1) {
    goToSlide(0);
    return;
  }
  currentSlide++;
  goToSlide(currentSlide);
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentSlide <= 0) {
    goToSlide(numberOfImages - 1);
    return;
  }
  currentSlide--;
  goToSlide(currentSlide);
});

function goToSlide(slideNumber) {
  slideContainer.style.transform =
    'translateX(-' + slideWidth * slideNumber + 'px)';

  currentSlide = slideNumber;
  setActiveClass();
}

function setActiveClass() {
  //set active class to slide
  let currentActive = document.querySelector('.slide-img.active');
  currentActive.classList.remove('active');
  slideImage[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
  //set active class to dot
  let currentDot = document.querySelector('.single-dot.active');
  currentDot.classList.remove('active');
  navigationDots.children[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method, which takes a function and executes it at a specified interval (in milliseconds). In the following example, it's set to advance one slide every three seconds. There's also a stop function that you can invoke if, say, someone clicks on one of the dots in your slide nav.

```js
let autoplay = null;

function autoplayStart() {
  const nextSlide = currentSlide + 1;
  autoplay = setInterval(goToSlide(nextSlide, 3000);
}

function autoplayStop() {
  clearInterval(autoplay);
}

function init() {
  slideImage.forEach((img, i) => {
    img.style.left = i * 100 + '%';
  });
  slideImage[0].classList.add('active');

  autoplayStart();

  createNavigationDots();
}
```